# Counting the number of times a value has appeared in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to count the amount of times the word "White" appears but I do not want to have a sum in one cell.  I want to count and place that number next to that specific white while placing the value of the previous white in the cells that are not white.

For example I want the Excel spreadsheet to do this:

[image]

Comment: The `CountIf()` function is made for cases like these, nothing advanced about that and certainly not extremely advanced :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try below `COUNTIF()` formula.

```
=COUNTIF($D$2:D2,D2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `countif` function will fetch you the results you want.

[image]